# How can I run AI4Bharat-Indic-TTS on colab

Tags: text-to-speech

I have seen a online repository of AI4Bharat TTS model. I want to run that on google colab but the instructions are too tough. Can anybody help me with that?

The repo link is: https://github.com/AI4Bharat/Indic-TTS

I tried to run that on colab but failed completely since the instructions are very unclear.